# Postman - how to obtain Azure Active Directory token using sign in form?

Tags: azure-active-directory, postman

Is is possible to obtain an AAD token in Postman by letting the user to Sign In using the standard AAD sign in form?

I know how to obtain token using the request to AAD (grant_type = client_credentials) but such a token does not have a UPN (user identity).

I would like to somehow type in my credentials in Postman and get the token. So it is a manual interaction, the user(me) needs to manually sign in - the same way how ie. Visual Studio verifies your identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/authorization) cannot popup the sign in page as it only does HTTP requests.  As you stated, it can do confidential client flows.

What you could do is hand-construct an auth request, sign in, and grab the auth code. Then take that auth code and drop it into the [Postman authorization](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/authorization) form, and let it hit the Azure AD token endpoint:
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token`
[The Azure AD protocol referene](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code) will be super helpful for you.

I think if you're wanting to quickly generate Access Tokens your best bet is to pick a framework/language and build a lightweight app that gets and logs tokens. Azure AD has a [Python Flask sample for the v2 endpoint](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-python-flask-graphapi-web-v2) that takes 5 minutes to setup and could be converted to printing out access tokens. If you want to use v1, you can checkout the list of samples at the [Azure AD developer guide](https://aka.ms/aaddev).

Comment: I see, maybe an interesting idea to implement in Postman. Anyways, I was thinking exactly about what you suggested - build a small app to let user sign in and get the token on callback. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Postman now offers the ability to "Authorize using browser." You'll need to make changes to your AAD application to support it in addition to configuring Postman.

### Configure your AAD application

Add a redirect URI to your AAD application for Postman to receive the authorization code. In the AAD Portal, navigate to your app registration, then to the "Authentication" tab, then add `https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback` as a new redirect URI. This URI was provided by Postman when you check the `✅ Authorize using browser` box (below) and is also documented on their website.

### Configure Postman

You can set this up under "Authorization" for a single request, a folder of requests, or a Collection. Open the "Authorization" tab and select `OAuth 2.0`. Under the "Configure New Token" section, enter the following information:

1. Token Name: anything you want. I chose the name of the AAD application.
2. Grant Type: `Authorization Code (With PKCE)`
3. Callback URL: check the `✅ Authorize using browser` box
4. Auth URL: copy this from the AAD portal under Overview > Endpoints (on top bar) > OAuth 2.0 authorization endpoint (v2). Mine looks like `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`
5. Access token URL: copy this from the AAD portal under Overview > Endpoints (on top bar) > OAuth 2.0 token endpoint (v2). Mine looks like `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/oauth2/v2.0/token`
6. Client ID: copy this from the AAD portal under Overview. It's also commonly referred to as an "Application ID" and is a GUID.
7. Client Secret: leave blank (not used by this grant type)
8. Code Challenge Method: `SHA-256`
9. Code Verifier: leave blank or provide your own
10. Scope: the scopes you're requesting in your token, separated by spaces
11. State: leave blank or provide a value such as a random GUID.
12. Client Authentication: `Send as Basic Auth Header` (not used by this grant type)

Refer to [Postman's documentation on OAuth 2.0 options](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/authorization/#requesting-an-oauth-20-token) for more information.

### Get a token

Click `Get New Access Token` to open the auth flow in your machine's default web browser. After authentication, it should redirect back to the Postman application and a new token will be created with the name you provided earlier for "Token Name." Select "Use Token" in the top-right corner of the popup to copy it into your current token. If the token expires and your requests start failing authorization (probably a 401 or 403 error), you can revisit this tab and get a new access token.

Occasionally, you may want to visit Current Token > Access Token > Manage Tokens > Delete > Expired tokens, otherwise you'll be inundated with nearly-identical tokens.

Comment: Under "Configure your AAD Application", note that the return URL needs to be added to the "Mobile and Desktop Application" redirect URLs, not "Web".

Comment: After I log in via browser and am redirected back to Postman, I get "Authentication failed" and the console says "Error: invalid_client".

Comment: That error is listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-aadsts-error-codes) and I believe it requires an admin of the tenant to [consent to the application's permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#request-the-permissions-from-a-directory-admin).

Comment: @Adam Thanks, figured it out. Postman actually does have a more descriptive error on the redirect webpage hidden in the URL. That error was "The client has requested access to a resource which is not listed in the requested permissions in the client application". I was requesting the scope "https://management.azure.com/.default" but I had not added that API permission to my app registration (Azure Service Management -> user_impersonation).

Comment: one comment though, that configuring
> Client Authentication: Send as Basic Auth Header (not used by this grant type)
is resulting in a `Error: AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_id'`

Following another advice I found, switching to "Send client credentials in body" works for me 

(not using "Client Secret"! :))